# What is an "XYZM" measurement model?

Tags: spatialite, linear-referencing

[SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html) supports a remarkable number of different dimension models.

Interestingly, some of their values support a "measure" coordinate (XYM, XYZM). How would this measure-coordinate be used, and what is the correct term for searching to figure out how it is used?

Answer (score 24):

Found this in the [FDO data concepts](http://fdo.osgeo.org/files/fdo/docs/FDG_FDODevGuide/files/WS7106c181349dd8d016672d6105df83c6e7-7fff.htm) page:

> A geometry is represented using geometric constructs either defined as
>   lists of one or more XY or XYZ points or defined parametrically, for
>   example, as a circular arc. While geometry typically is two- or
>   three-dimensional, it may also contain the **measurement dimension
>   (M)** to provide the basis for dynamic segments.

So M stands for measurement dimension.

Here's another useful definition from [a mailing list](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/4D-points-td3598428.html):

> m' is 'measure' an extra axis of **information not associated with the
>   cartesian x/y/z space**. The most common use for 'measure' is actually
>   for 'measurements', the adding of physically known measurements about 
>   a feature to the abstract 'feature' represented in x/y space in the 
>   GIS. For example, highway management systems often understand the 
>   location of facilities in terms of 'mile posts'. So, in addition to 
>   x/y coordinates, each vertex is also assigned a 'mile' measurement in 
>   'm' which allows the system to accurately place facility information 
>   relative to the 'milepost' system. (Why not just use the x/y 
>   coordinates and calculate distances off of them? Because they are 
>   representational, the distances calculated from the x/y will not be 
>   the same as the actual milepost measurements.)

Comment: It also can refer to a linear measure, as in a [linear referencing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_referencing).

Answer (score 10):

Or... You can think of M being any kind of variable for a given location, like temperature, time,... which isn't directly interpreted as a location.