# Difference between QgsPoint, QgsPointXY and QgsGeometry.fromPointXY() in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, geometry, xy

I am using PyQGIS. What is the difference between:

1. `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x, y))`
2. `QgsPointXY(x, y)`
3. `QgsPoint(x, y)`

When I print these three options, I get:

```py
print(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x1, y1)))
<QgsGeometry: Point (59777 -266560)>
print(QgsPointXY(x1, y1))
<QgsPointXY: POINT(59777 -266560)>
print(QgsPoint(x1, y1))
<QgsPoint: Point (59777 -266560)>
```

`(x1,y1)` are specific coordinates that I used as a test.

I don't understand the difference between these objects, and I need to know because there are some methods that work only in one or two of them. For example, the `intersect` method does not work for `QgsPoint` (at least it didn't work when I tried to check which feature the point intersected with).

Comment: There is better documentation since QGIS 3.20 in the API docs: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsPoint.html + https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsPointXY.html, highlighting the differences and suggested use cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `QgsPoint` is a point class which supports Z (3D) and M values. ([What are Z and M?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/39131/29431))

  ```
  x, y, z, m = 10, 10, 20, 5

  QgsPoint(x, y) # 2D
  # <QgsPoint: Point (10 10)>

  QgsPoint(x, y, z) # 3D
  # <QgsPoint: PointZ (10 10 20)>

  QgsPoint(x, y, z, m) # 3D and M
  # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 10 20 5)>
  ```
- `QgsPointXY` is a point class used for just 2D representation of a point. It doesn't support Z and M values.

  ```
  QgsPointXY(x, y)
  # <QgsPointXY: POINT(10 10)>

  QgsPointXY(x, y, z)
  # TypeError: QgsPointXY(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  #   ....
  ```
- `QgsPoint` and `QgsPointXY` objects can be converted into each other.

  ```
  qgs_point = QgsPoint(x, y, z, m)
  QgsPointXY(qgs_point)  # In this case Z and M values are dropped.
  # <QgsPointXY: POINT(10 10)>

  qgs_pointxy = QgsPointXY(x, y)
  QgsPoint(qgs_pointxy)
  # <QgsPoint: Point (10 10)>
  ```

  You should be aware of that a `QgsPoint` or a `QgsPointXY` object is not a geometry in terms of PyQGIS.
- `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY()` is a static method which is used for creating a point geometry in 2D and it takes a `QgsPointXY` object as argument.

  ```
  QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x, y))
  # <QgsGeometry: Point (10 10)>
  ```
- `intersect`, `ìntersection` etc. are methods of `QgsGeometry`. So they don't work for `QgsPoint` and `QgsPointXY` objects.

---

- So, can I pass `x, y` to `fromPointXY` as arguments (`QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(x, y)` or `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY([x, y])`)?
  No. You get error.
- Can I pass a `QgsPoint` object to `fromPointXY`?
  No. You get error. But this works: `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(qgs_point))`
- Then why are there two seperate classes to create a point?
  The geographic vector data model is based on points and most of the users use 2D vector data. Therefore, I guess, the developers must have decided to define separate classes for 2D and 3D points so that point information, which most users do not use, doesn't occupy more space in memory.

That's all I can explain. If I have provided incorrect information please correct it.

Answer (score 4):

**QgsPoint** is derived directly from `QgsAbstractGeometry`

**QgsPointXY** it is not derived from QgsPoint, but there are many methods to switch from one to the other.

`QgsPointXY` is derived from `QgsReferencedPointXY` which in turn comes from `QgsReferencedGeometryBase`

You will find many similarities

`QgsGeometry.fromPointXY()` allows you to create a geometry from a QgsPointXY. Remember that to add entities to a layer you must pass geometries to the features, this makes the process uniform, because there are many types of entities points, lines, polygons, multipoints....

The `geometry` class on the other hand facilitates geoprocesses regardless of the type of entity that created it

Comment: This information is wrong. `QgsPoint` is capable of storing Z and M values. `QgsPointXY` can only handle 2D information. There is nothing about "old" and "new" to it. `QgsPoint` is based on `QgsAbstractGeometry` and can be put into a `QgsGeometry`. Both have their use cases. There is nothing about "old" and "new" to it.

Comment: Sorry for being that direct.

Comment: On the contrary Master, thank you for clarifying, we are here to learn and rectify :)
My beginnings with PyQGis were watching your Colombia course and Olaya's course, both by youtube