# Extracting x,y coordinates from QgsGeometry: Point(x, y) using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, pyqgis-3, xy, qgs

I'm trying to extract the coordinates of a feature vertex. When I write on my editor

```py
print(vertex)
```

what I get is

```py
<QgsGeometry: Point(58746.43000004297, -256665.088999123)>
```

But when I try to extract the coordinates,

```py
print(vertex.x)
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'x'

How do I extract the coordinates x, and y?

If it is not possible with `<QgsGeometry: Point(x,y)>`, then how do I simply convert to a form that allows me to extract the coordinates?

Comment: yes, it says it's not callable...

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could get the same exception [`AttributeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'x'
```

after running the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsGeometry

vertex = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(58746.43000004297, -256665.088999123))
print(vertex.x)
```

When one types `print(type(vertex))` it returns you a [`QgsGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html) class.

There are several approaches you may get the x and y coordinates of a vertex/point:

1. One way is to convert the `QgsGeometry` class into a [`QgsPointXY`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html) class using the [`asPoint()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a77bddd38cd041a4e2988fa8e014c060f) method and then using two others methods [`x()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html#a031c77e7533369f55cbd85b52cd4ed1f) and [`y()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html#ab6d04669c5b31a8ad56bef4385e8f359) to get your coordinates.

   ```py
   from qgis.core import QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY

   geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(58746.43000004297, -256665.088999123))
   pt = geom.asPoint() # QgsPointXY
   print(pt.x(), pt.y())
   ```
2. From another side the `QgsGeometry` class possess a [`vertexAt()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a4de6615ad51648577d66983c6efd5203) method that will return a [`QgsPoint`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html) representing a vertex at a certain index. I have not seen your features, but most likely each `QgsGeometry` is not a multi-part, which means each contains only one point. Hence, one may simply approach each geometry via a `0`-index and afterwards use the `x()` and `y()` methods again.

   ```py
   from qgis.core import QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY

   geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(58746.43000004297, -256665.088999123))
   pt = geom.vertexAt(0) # QgsPoint
   print(pt.x(), pt.y())
   ```
3. There is a [`constGet()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a6418c395776ccc5a13466a5d28039225) method of the `QgsGeometry` class available.

   > Returns a non-modifiable (const) reference to the underlying abstract geometry primitive.

   ```py
   from qgis.core import QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY

   geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(58746.43000004297, -256665.088999123))
   geom_ = geom.constGet()
   print(geom_.x(), geom_.y())
   ```

All the above solutions will return the same output:

```
58746.43000004297 -256665.088999123
```

---

**References:**

- [Difference between QgsPoint, QgsPointXY and QgsGeometry.fromPointXY() in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377881/difference-between-qgspoint-qgspointxy-and-qgsgeometry-frompointxy-in-pyqgis)