Extracting coordinates from shapely geometry polygon with PyQGIS
I have the following code to generate a polygon from some calculated points (x/y pairs a,b,c,d) and rotate it by a given angle (Line_Head) around a given point (Rot_Point). This works.
"""Try to rotate a North-up box"""
Box_OE = FSOLE - ((BPL/2)*BinX)
Box_ON = FSOLN - (BinY/2)
Box_TRE = Box_OE + BG_Width
Box_TRN = Box_ON + BG_Length
a = [Box_OE, Box_ON]
b = [Box_OE, Box_TRN]
c = [Box_TRE, Box_TRN]
d = [Box_TRE, Box_ON]
Rot_Point = [FSOLE, FSOLN]

Pol = geometry.Polygon([a,b,c,d])
bounds = geometry.box(*Pol.bounds)
bounds_rotated = affinity.rotate(bounds, Line_Head, origin=Rot_Point)
print(bounds_rotated)

The output from the print is:
POLYGON ((469444.1684401436 8035483.5273151435, 478263.09490447957 8043038.430465204, 478100.4489320498 8043228.289003703, 469281.5224677138 8035673.385853643, 469444.1684401436 8035483.5273151435))

As it's a POLYGON, the first and last pairs are the same.
What I would like to do is extract either 4 x/y pairs or 8 individual coordinates for the 4 corners of the  new rotated POLYGON above. I need to individual coordinates to perform some other calculations.

This is part of a larger QGIS plugin I have written so I'd rather keep it within the plugin than export it to something else.

With the code below, I could also get the same shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon-object:
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]
ext = layer.extent()
center = ext.center()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()

from shapely import geometry, affinity

a = [xmin, ymin]
b = [xmin, ymax]
c = [xmax, ymax]
d = [xmax, ymin]
Rot_Point = [center.x(), center.y()]
Pol = geometry.Polygon([a, b, c, d])
bounds = geometry.box(*Pol.bounds)
bounds_rotated = affinity.rotate(bounds, 90, origin=Rot_Point)
print(bounds_rotated)

So, why to make life more complicated and not using the __geo_interface__ method?
That will return:
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((6363279.701102798, 6156974.654581311), (6362876.6452906, 6156974.654581311), (6362876.6452906, 6156234.080487354), (6363279.701102798, 6156234.080487354), (6363279.701102798, 6156974.654581311)),)}

Afterwards one can extract either 4 x/y pairs or 8 individual coordinates for the 4 corners of the new rotated POLYGON above:
coords = bounds_rotated.__geo_interface__.get('coordinates')
pairs = coords[0][:-1]

It outputs the following:
((6363279.701102798, 6156974.654581311), (6362876.6452906, 6156974.654581311), (6362876.6452906, 6156234.080487354), (6363279.701102798, 6156234.080487354))

Last but not least, to accomplish the final step (which is a pure Pythonic question) I would suggest using a simple dict:
xy = {}
for i, pair in enumerate(pairs, 1):
    xy[f"x{i}"], xy[f"y{i}"] = pair[0], pair[1]

One will end up with the following output:
{'x1': 6363279.701102798, 'y1': 6156974.654581311, 'x2': 6362876.6452906, 'y2': 6156974.654581311, 'x3': 6362876.6452906, 'y3': 6156234.080487354, 'x4': 6363279.701102798, 'y4': 6156234.080487354}

Also possible by means globals() and exec():
for i, pair in enumerate(pairs, 1):
    exec(f"x{i} = pair[0]")
    exec(f"y{i} = pair[1]")

See these threads for more details: StackOverflow | How can you dynamically create variables? and StackOverflow | How do I create variable variables?.

This works to get me to your last line. How would I assign each coordinate to a different variable? e.g. x1=6363279.701102798, Y1=6156974.654581311, x2=6362876.6452906 and so on for all 8.

If you want to avoid the dependency on Shapely etc then you can do it entirely with in the PyQGIS framework using vertexAt:
 for i in range(bounds_rotated.vertexCount() - 1):
    print(bounds_rotated.vertexAt(i))


Also see my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380788/99589
